# Pie Chart VS Doughnut Chart: When to use each?

Tags: interaction-design, design, human-interface-guideline, charts, piechart

What is the UX rationale behind picking a *doughnut chart* vs a *pie chart* or viceversa?

I'm asking because I'm intrigued as to why a designer would prefer to represent data with a pie instead of a doughnut. Are there any "hidden" advantages of one over the other? Did the designer of the doughnut chart just felt like adding white-space to the pie chart would make it more aesthetic and truly has no added value?

Looking around the web, most if not all of the articles I've found just treat both charts as if they were the same.

Comment: This feels like a poll rather than a request for help with a particular UX problem. What has triggered this question? Is there a problem with one or the other that you are trying to solve or evaluate? What research have you done to find an answer?

Comment: "What has triggered the question?" In making a choice, as simple it may be, I'm asking myself "Why?". Digging through this site, I've understood that is important to ask "Why" when designing an interface having in mind the user expectations. As for research, I did a Google Search, found a lot of people just claiming them to be "the same". I cam e here to see if there was indeed differences between the two, so I could make a choice in one of my designs.

Comment: You may find this an interesting read on why both types are bad and should rarely (contextually) ever be used: http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/08-21-07.pdf

Comment: Yes, it is important to ask why but it's also important to ask the right 'why'. The question you have asked is effectively an opinion poll - opinion polls are only based on opinion not verifiable fact. What is the problem you are trying to solve by choosing one or the other? If it's purely aesthetic then you should really be testing with your users to find which they find most appealing. If there's some other problem you are trying to solve then you need to explain that properly and show what research you have done towards finding an answer. "I'm making a choice" is not a UX problem.

Comment: @mrcharlie Totally agree. Pie charts if you have 2 values to chart, something else if you have >2. They're really not that usable for 3 or more values.

Comment: @mrcharlie Great insight. I read the document and the arguments shown there are very compelling. I will now only use Pie/Doughnuts when I have two values to graph.

Comment: @AndrewMartin: With all due respect, and not trying to pick a fight here as you are clearly much more experienced and professional than myself in these matters, I disagree. At least for this particular question. When presented with two choices that seem equal, what would be the rationale to choose one over the other? Why did someone create  new type of chart equal to another? Was it purely aesthetic and in fact it doesn't matter? Or does it? Some have posted benefits of one over the other, or not to use them at all. If its the way the question is asked that is troubling you, I have edited it.

Comment: Neither - pie charts and doughnut charts are poor for comparing things if you have more than 2 segments - mainly because it is hard to work out relative size if the segments are a similar size. A bar graph is a much better choice for comparing multiple things. Read any book by Stephen Few.

Comment: @SteveD: Thank you for the author recommendation. I was looking for one to read and learn more about data visualizations. About your comment, thanks for adding to the previous comment by "mrcharlie". After reading the document he posted, indeed more than 2 segments in a pie chart gives a poor result.

Comment: @RainierMallolI I definitely recommend his second edition of Information Dashboard Design. By far the best money I ever spent.

Comment: @SteveD: Thanks again! I will definetely start with that one. I'm pretty much hyped now, got some reading to do :)

Comment: I am always disappointed when things come down to opinion. There must be some physical characteristics or perceptual ideas or something to make a choice. Something should *win*. It is endlessly tiresome to encounter a growing multitude of options and just a big shrug when asked which to use. Stop shrugging and design the best possible solution! Then we will all just *use it* and stop wasting time.

Comment: @nocomprende: With regard to the choice between doughnut/pie charts on the one hand and bar charts on the other, there appear to be "physical characteristics and perceptual ideas" that strongly indicate that the latter type of figure is in almost any case the best possible solution. I haven't read the original studies in great detail, but it seems to be consensus in the data vis community that human beings are relatively good at comparing lengths (as in bar charts), but relatively poor at comparing angles (as in pie charts). So let's all just use bar charts and stop wasting time.

Comment: @Schmuddi Good. I agree. Next question: that idea of 100% bar charts is exasperating! When there are two bars next to each other, the same height, but one represents a much larger *quantity* than the other, I am dismayed. How is my perceptual system supposed to compare them? And if one bar really only amounts to 2% of the grand total, there is no point in breaking that bar down farther, just call it "misc." Can we throw out 100% bar charts also? And that Radar chart thing...

Comment: @nocomprende: If you want to get answers to your questions, then ask them as proper questions. The comment section is not the right place for this sort of discussion.

Comment: @Schmuddi I was going to write an Answer, but the question is On Hold, so I could not say what I was intending to. I think the answer to Opinion-based questions is to give the proper answer and then everyone start using it. I don't know why they are closed instead. It thwarts getting the right answers out there. If we cannot agree on the right answer it simply shows that we do not know enough yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A doughnut (or donut) chart serves a similar purpose to a pie chart, except that it is able to show more than one set of data. Think of it as a pie chart with an additional dimension.

See the example below, where a donut chart shows sales for different regions for two separate years. This allows to compare data more easily with respect to time (see how easy is to see that the US sales decreased in 2006), and takes much less space than two pie charts put one aside the other.

It works well between 2 and 4 sets of data (after that limit, it's going to appear crammed) and for a limited number of slices for each set (since only two slices are guaranteed to be aligned, such as US and Europe in the picture below, comparing other slices is going to be difficult).

[image]

Comment: Yeah, and see how much more difficult it is to see whether the sales for Asia increased or decreased. To be honest, I wouldn't consider this to be a figure that is working particularly well.

Comment: That's the downside of donut charts -- only two regions for each set are guaranteed to be aligned (here it's US and Europe).  I've updated my answer, since this is a good point.

Comment: This is poor data representation. 2006 data appears to be "larger" than 2005, as it takes up more area. For example, look at the United States data between the two years--it appears, visually, that the value in 2006 is greater than 2005 because it takes up more area. I would **strongly discourage** the use of this type of graph for comparisons. There are many other much clearer ways to depict this data.

Comment: The purpose of a donut chart, as that of a pie chart, is mainly to compare *percentages* i.e. values of different slices whose sum makes up 100%.

Comment: If you have to put numbers on the pie, you are already failing to communicate with the data visualisation. A bar graph would be so much better in your pie example.

Comment: A bar chart needs numbers, too; moreover, it fails to communicate that the values sum up to 100%.  In a pie/donut chart, this information is immediately conveyed.

Comment: @dr01 I agree that it's useful for showing parts of a single, whole data set, but my point is that I don't think it's an effective way to compare *two different* data sets. Again, when "nesting" these data sets, the 2006 data set occupies more visual space, so it incorrectly implies that the values are greater than the 2005 data.